# Constructor bean injection with custom annotation

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I would like to inject a bean (lets call it `clientStub`) into my `service` bean.

There are two requirements for that:

- In order to create the `clientStub` bean, I need to access the `@Client` annotation, that carries some important information that are used to lookup the relevant configuration in the properties.
- It must support constructor based injection (and `@Bean` method parameter injection)

Expected usage:

```
@Autowired
public MyService(
        @Client("invoice-manager") InvoiceManagerClientStub clientStub,
        SomeOtherBean bean1, ...) {
```

or

```
@Bean
MyService myService(
        @Client("invoice-manager") InvoiceManagerClientStub clientStub,
        SomeOtherBean bean1, ...) {
```

So I would like to do the same as the `@Value` annotation e.g. derive the value from the annotation on the parameter (plus some internal lookups).

Unfortunately, the usual `BeanFactory`s don't seem to be aware of the target's annotations.

**Alternatives considered**

Using an `BeanPostProcessor` to inject the values into annotated fields. Well, this is what I'm currently doing, but it doesn't feel right to have an immutable class with a single setter for injection.

Injecting it to a field and then exposing it as a bean or manually invoking the constructor is even worse.

Creating a proxy instance of the injected class. This isn't possible since the injected classes are generated + final and not part of my library.

Derive the configuration from the bean name: Not sure how to implement this and how to explain the user what the configuration parameters should be named in their properties files. I also would like to avoid bean name conflicts.

**Non-Goals**

Overwriting any core beans. I would like to distribute the extension as a library (spring-boot based), so any excessive replacement of spring internal beans should be avoided.

**TLDR**

How do I tell spring to resolve the parameter using my annotation's value (resolver)?